# Sort, match and complete a dataframe of categorical variables

Tags: r

I have created this dataset

```
db_a <- c("name", "dob", "healthstatus")

db_b <- c("name", "sanitation", "height", "weight")

db_c <- c("dob", "adiposity")

db_d <- c( "healthstatus", "adiposity", "postcode", "match", "doornum")

db_a <- as.data.frame(db_a)
db_b <- as.data.frame(db_b)
db_c <- as.data.frame(db_c)
db_d <- as.data.frame(db_d)

db_a <- db_a %>% mutate(number = 1:n())
db_b <- db_b %>% mutate(number = 1:n())
db_c <- db_c %>% mutate(number = 1:n())
db_d <- db_d %>% mutate(number = 1:n())

merge_test <- list(db_a, db_b, db_c, db_d) %>% 
  reduce(full_join, by = "number") %>% 
  select(-number)
```

I want to be able to have a unique row for each unique value in each column (and match them and make them be on the same row for those that occur in more than 1 column). For example, 'name' is common in db_a and db_b, so that row would be NA in db_c and db_d

I want the output to be as [image]

Answer (score 1):

(Option 1 since deleted.)

## Option 2: combine into a single frame

This option changes things slightly, converting four frames with a unique `db_*` name and a singular `number` into common columns of `word`, `number`, and the source (if you really need the original frame).

I'll use `dplyr` for this, for the use of `lst` (auto-naming list elements), `bind_rows` (for the combining), and the follow-on aggregation.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_wider
L2 <- lst(db_a, db_b, db_c, db_d) |>
  lapply(setNames, c("word", "number")) |>
  bind_rows(.id = "src") |>
  pivot_wider(id_cols = word, names_from = src, values_from = number) |>
  mutate(across(-word, ~ if_else(is.na(.x), NA, word))) |>
  select(-word)
L2
# # A tibble: 10 × 4
#    db_a         db_b       db_c      db_d        
#    <chr>        <chr>      <chr>     <chr>       
#  1 name         name       NA        NA          
#  2 dob          NA         dob       NA          
#  3 healthstatus NA         NA        healthstatus
#  4 NA           sanitation NA        NA          
#  5 NA           height     NA        NA          
#  6 NA           weight     NA        NA          
#  7 NA           NA         adiposity adiposity   
#  8 NA           NA         NA        postcode    
#  9 NA           NA         NA        match       
# 10 NA           NA         NA        doornum
```

For convenience here, we could use

```r
L2 <- mget(grep("^db_", ls(), value=TRUE)) |>
  lapply(setNames, ...) |> ...
```

though that only works if your naming convention is the same for all variables, and you have no other similarly-named variables in your environment.

Comment: Thank you! That's really useful but not exactly what I am looking for at the minute. I have added my desired output to the question now which might make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses a helper function to keep track of all words seen so far, which is used as a kind of “master key”:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

join_words <- function(x, y) {
  key_y <- grep("^db_", names(y), value = TRUE)
  full_join(x, y, by = c(word = key_y), keep = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(word = coalesce(word, .data[[key_y]]))
}

list(db_a, db_b, db_c, db_d) %>% 
  reduce(join_words, .init = data.frame(word = character())) %>%
  select(!word)
```

Result:

```
           db_a       db_b      db_c         db_d
1          name       name      <NA>         <NA>
2           dob       <NA>       dob         <NA>
3  healthstatus       <NA>      <NA> healthstatus
4          <NA> sanitation      <NA>         <NA>
5          <NA>     height      <NA>         <NA>
6          <NA>     weight      <NA>         <NA>
7          <NA>       <NA> adiposity    adiposity
8          <NA>       <NA>      <NA>     postcode
9          <NA>       <NA>      <NA>        match
10         <NA>       <NA>      <NA>      doornum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst(db_a, db_b, db_c, db_d) %>%
   map_df(~rename_with(.x, ~str_remove(.x, '_\\w+')), .id = 'name')%>%
   mutate(number = db)%>%
   pivot_wider(values_from = db) %>%
   select(-number)

# A tibble: 10 × 4
   db_a         db_b       db_c      db_d        
   <chr>        <chr>      <chr>     <chr>       
 1 name         name       NA        NA          
 2 dob          NA         dob       NA          
 3 healthstatus NA         NA        healthstatus
 4 NA           sanitation NA        NA          
 5 NA           height     NA        NA          
 6 NA           weight     NA        NA          
 7 NA           NA         adiposity adiposity   
 8 NA           NA         NA        postcode    
 9 NA           NA         NA        match       
10 NA           NA         NA        doornum
```

---

```
lst(db_a, db_b, db_c, db_d) %>%
   imap(~mutate(.x,number = .x[[.y]]))%>%
   reduce(full_join, 'number')%>%
   select(-number)

           db_a       db_b      db_c         db_d
1          name       name      <NA>         <NA>
2           dob       <NA>       dob         <NA>
3  healthstatus       <NA>      <NA> healthstatus
4          <NA> sanitation      <NA>         <NA>
5          <NA>     height      <NA>         <NA>
6          <NA>     weight      <NA>         <NA>
7          <NA>       <NA> adiposity    adiposity
8          <NA>       <NA>      <NA>     postcode
9          <NA>       <NA>      <NA>        match
10         <NA>       <NA>      <NA>      doornum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tables <- c("db_a", "db_b", "db_c", "db_d")
out <- data.frame(ref = sort(unique(unlist(mget(tables)))))
out[tables] <- lapply(mget(tables), \(x) replace(out$ref, !out$ref %in% x, ""))


#             ref         db_a       db_b      db_c         db_d
# 1     adiposity                         adiposity    adiposity
# 2           dob          dob                  dob             
# 3       doornum                                        doornum
# 4  healthstatus healthstatus                      healthstatus
# 5        height                  height                       
# 6         match                                          match
# 7          name         name       name                       
# 8      postcode                                       postcode
# 9    sanitation              sanitation                       
# 10       weight                  weight
```